# Hatcher Example 3E.2, Cup Products in Lens Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

First, http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf is a link to the book.

[image]

This is the first paragraph of Example 3E.2. I have two questions about what I can't understand.

1. How the $2n$-cell of $L$ is the homeomorphic image of the $2n$-cell in $S^{2n+1}$ formed by the points $\cos \theta (z_1,...,z_n,0)+\sin \theta (0,...,0,1)$ with $\sum_i z_i^2=1$ and $0<\theta \leq \pi$?
2. How cellular cohomology implies that $H^{2n}(\Bbb CP^\infty;\Bbb Z_m)\to H^{2n}(L;\Bbb Z_m)$ is an isomorphism?

Thanks in advance.